# Opamp circuit instability

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm having an issue with the circuit bellow, it is supposed to be a current limiting circuit but is oscillating. I know probably is an issue with poles and zeros, but with this configuration I'm not really sure what I'm able to do. Anyone has any suggestion of something I could try? Besides changing the opamp is there something else I can do?

[image: Schematic]

[image: Waveform]

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Firstly, BJTs can have a very long turn off time if they get saturated (several microseconds).  Because of the very high gain in your circuit, you are probably saturating T1 at least.  This will tend to make your control loop unstable since the transistors will be stuck on and the op-amp will over compensate when trying to turn them off.

With the op-amp output at 3.3V...
T1_BASE_CURRENT = (3.3V - 0.7V)/10K = 260uA
T1_COLLECTOR_CURRENT = 100 * 260uA = 26mA 
26mA * 820 ohms = 21.32V.
21.32V > 12V - 2 * VBE, so T1 can saturate when the op-amp is at max output.

Let's examine some changes that could be made to improve things.

It looks like you are going for a 100mA current limit in this particular setup.

Working backwards from the output, and assuming T3 has a gain of about 100, that means you need a base current of about 1mA on T3.

The base current comes from T1.  If we move R3 to the emitter of T1 then T1 becomes a voltage controlled current source.  The collector current is about equal to the emitter voltage on T3 divided by R3.  If we make R3 = 1K then the maximum current coming from T1 is around (3.3V - 0.7V) / 1K = 2.6mA.  We only needed 1mA, but 2.6mA gives us some margin in case the transistor gain is a bit lower on T1 or T3.

Next add 1K resistor R5 across the base-emitter of T3.  This will help T3 turn off faster.

Finally, add the compensation components similar to those suggested by @Andyaka.  Because of where we moved R3, the input impedance to T1 base is already going to be pretty high.  In that case we might move R2 and use it for the compensation.

The main limiting factor is going to be the 350kHz bandwidth of the INA180A1.  We need the time constant on the feedback to be much longer than 1/350kHz = 2.8us.  Using 2.7nF / 10K gives us a 27us time constant, which should be sufficient to stabilize the loop.

27us is also short enough that if you had a short circuit, it would not persist for very long (worst case a few times 27us).

**I also noticed that you don't have a decoupling capacitor on U2.  You might want to add that.**

Comment: Your sugestion of moving the T1 base resistor to the emiter is quite good since it removes the beta depency of the transistor, now I'm feeling a bit dumb for not thinking about that. About the decoupling capacitor I have it my board, just forgot to add it on the simulation. I'll will try rearrange my circuit with your sugestions and see if it improves

Answer (score 8):

Op-amps have a hard enough time remaining stable in unity gain just with resistors feeding back from their output. In your case you have far outreached what can be expected: -

[image]

So, you have an extra voltage gain within the op-amp's closed-loop of maybe 200,000 and that op-amp is just going to sing its little heart out by oscillating crazily.

> *Besides changing the opamp is there something else I can do?*

Try this to lower the op-amp's loop gain at high frequencies (where the problem lies): -

[image]

If you are lucky, you might be able to get away with 10 nF and 1 kΩ.

From my comment below, this is what I would suggest to reduce open-loop gain further: -

[image]

The modifications around the transistors immediately reduce open-loop gain by maybe 500 to 1000 compared to the original circuit. Now, you might be in with a small chance of this working with the localized filtering around the op-amp (in purple).

Of course you may still have to fiddle around with some of the resistor values to get the output current needed to drive the load (unspecified).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this circuit was meant to work as programable current limiting for a test jig, using a low pass on the feedback line will decrease hability of short circuit protection. Sadly even with the values you suggested and higher ones it seems to not be stable. I will need to retink my aproach most likely...

Comment: You could start by using an emitter resistor for T1 to reduce its localized gain. Then you might also consider a base resistor to ground for the same device to reduce gain further. Think about how much voltage swing you need on T3's base to hit the end stops in either direction. A localized base-emitter resistor on T3 of maybe a few hundred ohms is also going to reduce loop gain.